# Swift 4 Data reading options

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift4, nsdata

What is the correct translation of this Objective C code line to Swift 4?

```
NSData *mappedData =
  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL
                        options:NSDataReadingMappedAlways + NSDataReadingUncached
                          error:&error];
```

I tried this but it doesn't compile:

```
 Data(contentsOf: fileUrl, options: Data.ReadingOptions.dataReadingMapped | Data.ReadingOptions.uncached)
```

Comment: "I tried this but it doesn't compile:" And what is the error thrown by XCode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
do {

     // note it runs in current thread

    let data = try Data(contentsOf:fileURL, options: [.alwaysMapped , .uncached ] )

    print(data)

}
catch {

    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Not working for me – Exception : "The file couldn’t be opened."

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your Swift code.

First, the `options` need to be passed in as elements of an array, (not using the bitwise OR operator as you have - that method was deprecated several Swift versions back):

```
[.dataReadingMapped, .uncached]
```

Second, this initializer can throw an exception, so you need to account for that.

There are two ways to do that: inside a try-catch block, or via optional chaining.

If you want the ability to catch and respond to a specific error then use a try-catch block:

```
do {
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileURL, options: [.dataReadingMapped, .uncached])
    // Do something with data
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

If you don't care about recovering from specific errors, you can use optional chaining:

```
if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileURL, options: [.dataReadingMapped, .uncached]) {
    // Do something with data
} else {
    // It failed. Do something else.
}
```

I'd recommend Apple's Swift Programming Language book, if you're interested in switching from Objective-C to Swift:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329

Answer (score -1):

Try this and see

```
do {
    guard let fileURL = URL(string: "") else {
       return
    }
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL , options: Data.ReadingOptions(rawValue: Data.ReadingOptions.alwaysMapped.rawValue | Data.ReadingOptions.uncached.rawValue))
     print(data)
} catch {
    //print(error)
}
```

Comment: you too =D ....